# How many bytes will print command output in hex format in GDB?

Tags: gdb

I'm working on the bomb lab from CMU CSAPP class from this [site](http://csapp.cs.cmu.edu/3e/labs.html), the bomb binary is [here](http://csapp.cs.cmu.edu/3e/bomb.tar).

I found a very interesting thing using gdb while i am defusing `phase_3` of the bomb. I need to use a lot `p/x [MEMORY_ADDRESS]` while defusing `phase_3`, however, the output of the `print` command looks strange to me.

I tried to print against different memeory address using `p/x *[MEMORY_ADDRESS]`, the length of the output varied a lot. It sometimes gave me a 8-char output like `0x18244c8b`, sometimes gave me a 6-char output like `0x28250c`, or sometimes only a `0x0`.

In my understanding, while using `p/x *[MEMORY_ADDRESS]`, we are only print the hex value of the single byte resides in that memory address, which should only give us a 2-char output in hex format. *How does gdb decide how many bytes it will print while executing `p/x`?*

Thanks for looking at this problem.

Comment: If you're unsure about the size of the value you print, try `p/z` instead of `p/x`.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that, gdb is treating my memory address as a pointer to int, thus will always try to print 4 bytes, the reason i'm seeing varying output is because some ouputs have so many leading zeros. So `0xfe` is actually `0x000000fe`.

In this scenario, gdb's `print` command is always printing 4 bytes.